# troubles with insert query

Tags: sql

I've got table TClientsPayment with fields

```
idcontract,idclient,last_paid_time,paid,left_to_pay
```

and I need to insert data from this table to another table TClientsPaymentsHistory with fields

```
idcontract,idclient,last_paid_time,paid,late
```

where `late` is a `bit` field. `late` can be either 0 or 1. it depends on whether client has paid till 25.xx.xxxx. If not `late` = 1.

If I make a query

```
insert into TClientPaymentHistory
select idcontract,
       idclient,
       last_paid_time,
       paid
from TClientsPayments
```

then how to set `late` field in this insert query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause, here is a pseudo code of how you can do this:

```
insert into TClientPaymentHistory
select idcontract,
       idclient,
       last_paid_time,
       paid,
       CASE 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(day, last_paid_time, 'tell date here') <= something THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS late     
from TClientsPayments
```

Since you didn't specify what RDBMS you are using, you will need to determine the correct way to get the date difference depending on the SQL dialect you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, although you'll need to be clearer about the condition:

```
Insert into TClientPaymentHistory (
  idcontract, idclient, last_paid_time, paid, late
)
Select
   idcontract,
   idclient,
   last_paid_time,
   paid,
   Case When last_paid_time < 25.xx.xxxx then 0 else 1 end
From
  TclientPayments
```